# RabbitMQ crashes

Tags: rabbitmq, mnesia

My rabbitmq instance crashed with the following reason. I know nothing about Erlang so I cannot fully understand the stacktrace. I checked Mnesia's documentation. It seems that my rabbitmq crashed because some Mnesia transaction got aborted, and abort reason is rabbit_runtime_parameters and cluster_name missing? But what caused it?

```
=SUPERVISOR REPORT==== 9-Jun-2016::17:20:34 ===
Supervisor:
{<0.5605.7>,rabbit_connection_sup}
Context: child_terminated
Reason: {aborted,{no_exists,[rabbit_runtime_parameters,
cluster_name]}}
Offender: [{pid,<0.5607.7>},
{name,reader},
{mfargs,{rabbit_reader,start_link,[<0.5606.7>]}},
{restart_type,intrinsic},
{shutdown,4294967295},
{child_type,worker}]


=SUPERVISOR REPORT==== 9-Jun-2016::17:20:34 ===
Supervisor: {<0.5605.7>,rabbit_connection_sup}
Context: shutdown
Reason: reached_max_restart_intensity
Offender: [
{pid,<0.5607.7>}
,
{name,reader},
{mfargs,{rabbit_reader,start_link,[<0.5606.7>]}},
{restart_type,intrinsic},
{shutdown,4294967295},
{child_type,worker}]

Error in log handler
====================
Event: {info_msg,<0.83.0>,
{<0.5610.7>,"accepting AMQP connection ~p (~s)~n",
[<0.5610.7>,<<"192.168.100.69:44519 -> 172.17.0.6:5672">>]}}
Error: badarg
Stack trace: [{ets,lookup,
[rabbit_exchange,
{resource,<<"/">>,exchange,<<"amq.rabbitmq.log">>}],
[]},
{rabbit_misc,dirty_read,1,[]},
{rabbit_basic,publish,1,[]},
{rabbit_error_logger,publish1,4,[]},
{rabbit_error_logger,handle_event0,2,[]},
{rabbit_error_logger_file_h,safe_handle_event,3,[]},
{gen_event,server_update,4,[{file,"gen_event.erl"},{line,538}]},
{gen_event,server_notify,4,[{file,"gen_event.erl"},{line,520}]}]


=INFO REPORT==== 9-Jun-2016::17:20:39 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.5610.7> (192.168.100.69:44519 -> 172.17.0.6:5672)

=CRASH REPORT==== 9-Jun-2016::17:20:39 ===
crasher:
initial call: rabbit_reader:init/2
pid: <0.5610.7>
registered_name: []
exception exit: {aborted,
{no_exists,[rabbit_runtime_parameters,cluster_name]}}
in function mnesia:abort/1 (mnesia.erl, line 313)
in call from rabbit_runtime_parameters:lookup0/2
in call from rabbit_runtime_parameters:value0/2
in call from rabbit_reader:server_properties/1
in call from rabbit_reader:start_connection/3
in call from rabbit_reader:handle_input/3
in call from rabbit_reader:recvloop/4
in call from rabbit_reader:run/1
ancestors: [<0.5608.7>,rabbit_tcp_client_sup,rabbit_sup,<0.84.0>]
messages: [{'EXIT',#Port<0.225508>,normal}]
links: [<0.5608.7>]
dictionary: [{process_name,
{rabbit_reader,
<<"192.168.100.69:44519 -> 172.17.0.6:5672">>}}]
trap_exit: true
status: running
heap_size: 610
stack_size: 27
reductions: 1175
neighbours:
```

Comment: Which rabbitmq version are you using ?

Comment: RabbitMQ version is 3.5.6